# Geolocation not working in Android

Tags: android, geolocation

I am trying to get weather info via openweathermap , the problem is it not show any data via geolocation , I tested my app on real device , even am sure about permission in manifest

mainactivity

```
package com.example.vamshi.weathertest;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static TextView place;
    static TextView temp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        place = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.place);
        temp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.temp);

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(),false);

        //Log.i("Jimmy",provider+" hi");
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        Log.i("Jimmy","hi "+location);
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lng = location.getLongitude();
        Weather getData = new Weather();
        getData.execute("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + String.valueOf(lat) + "&lon=" + String.valueOf(lng) + "&appid=3c70f7d8f9e272cd6f73036a65228391");


    }
}
```

if i delete `" + String.valueOf(lat) + "` and `" + String.valueOf(lng) + "` from url  he working fine .

weather activity

```
package com.example.vamshi.weathertest;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Created by Vamshi on 5/14/2017.
 */

public class Weather extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

    String result;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        result = "";
        URL link;
        HttpURLConnection myconnection = null;

        try {
            link = new URL(urls[0]);
            myconnection = (HttpURLConnection)link.openConnection();
            InputStream in = myconnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader myStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(in);
            int data = myStreamReader.read();
            while(data!= -1){
                char current = (char)data;
                result+= current;
                data = myStreamReader.read();
            }
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        try {
            JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONObject main = new JSONObject(myObject.getString("main"));
            String temperature = main.getString("temp");
            String placeName = myObject.getString("name");

            MainActivity.place.setText(placeName);
            MainActivity.temp.setText(temperature);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any exception?

Comment: @EnamulHaque no

Answer (score 0):

Edit

```
getData.execute("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + 
  String.valueOf(lat) + "&lon=" + String.valueOf(lng) + 
  "&appid=3c70f7d8f9e272cd6f73036a65228391");
```

To

```
getData.execute("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + 
  lat + "&lon=" + lng + "&appid=3c70f7d8f9e272cd6f73036a65228391");
```

Comment: its same , if i delete all code for location manager working fine :(

Comment: That's why I ask you. Is there any exception? If there is no exception it will work fine..

Comment: do you want to give you teamv id to check out ?

Comment: Just replace a lat lng like 3.413991, -1.054688 (for example) it will show your desire result.

Comment: just try it getData.execute("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + 
  3.413991 + "&lon=" + -1.054688 + "&appid=3c70f7d8f9e272cd6f73036a65228391");

Comment: yes i do that is same now working , but i delete all code for location manger his working fine

Comment: Now you come to point ..... there is some problem with getting location ... such as your location is null

Comment: yes , i put like that "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat‌​=33&lon=44&appid=3c70f7d8f9e272cd6f73036a65228391 he work

Comment: If you want to directly get last detected location then you have to ensure that network provider is enabled. Otherwise you will get null location. so your code will not work.

Comment: what you mean network provider ? you mean permission ?

Comment: There is main 2 type of provider GPS_PROVIDER and NETWORK_PROVIDER

Comment: You must find out what err is going on ... it may permission prob, location provider. See logcat and find what is that err if any.